# What did I do wrong with this Legrand RRW600U wiring?

Tags: switch, motion-sensor, smart-switch

I just moved into a new house, and I'm trying to wire up TWO Legrand RRW600U 3-way occupancy switches to a light in the basement.  I want motion at the top or bottom of the stairs to turn on the light.
Currently... motion at the bottom will turn on the light, and this switch works just fine. Motion at the top of the stairs makes it click, but the light doesn't come on.  I can, however, manually turn the light on/off at the top of the stairs.  The indicator light on the switch upstairs will blink when it sees motion, so I don't think the motion sensor is broken or anything.

---

**Electrical Box Wiring**

**At the bottom of the stairs...**
The electrical box has 2 wire bundles:

A- 2-conductor + Ground, with the WHITE wire having 120V potential to ground.
---*I assume this comes from the light, since the WHITE wire is hot, not the black wire*

B- 3-conductor + Ground (black, white, red) going to the switch upstairs

**At the top of the stairs...**
The box has 1 wire bundle:

C -  3-conductor + Ground (black, white, red) going to the switch downstairs

---

**Switch wiring**

Each switch has a black, red, and yellow wire.  (And a ground screw, of course)

**At the bottom Switch:**

Black - connected to WHITE (hot) wire from the light (2 conductor bundle) and white wire going to the other switch (3 conductor bundle), all 3 wire nutted together

Red - Connected to BLACK wire from the light (2 conductor bundle)

Yellow - Connected to the RED wire in the 3 conductor bundle (Traveler), which is connected to the yellow wire on the other switch

**At the top Switch:**

Black - connected to WHITE (hot) wire bundle from the bottom switch (120v) (3 conductor bundle), which is connected to the black wire from the bottom switch

Red - NOT CONNECTED (per instructions)

Yellow - Connected to the RED wire in the 3 conductor bundle (Traveler), which is connected to the yellow wire on the other switch

**This leaves the BLACK wire from the 3 conductor bundle disconnected on BOTH ends.**

---

***THE BIG QUESTIONS:***
Why won't motion at the top of the stairs turn on the light?  Why did I end up with an extra wire in the 3 conductor bundle between the boxes that isn't used?

As I said above, the MOTION DETECTION upstairs seems to work because the indicator blinks when it sees motion, and the switch will click like it's trying to change.  The button on the switch can also manually turn the light on/off so it's not an issue with the switch being unable to operate the light, either.

Further, the switch upstairs was able to turn the light on/off when it was wired to a regular 3-way (duckbill mechanical) switch downstairs... but when I got a second of the same switch for downstairs, it stopped being able to operate the light via motion.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: That switch has two modes of operation:  Occupancy mode and vacancy mode.  Make sure the top-of-the-stairs switch is set to Occupancy.

Comment: Also, be sure the delay is set properly.  Occupancy detector on the stairs would turn into a very bad idea if the light turns off when you are in the middle.

Comment: Is this switch made to do this? That is, is using two of them this way authorized by the instructions?

Comment: What is happening with grounds? You didn't mention them...

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the boxes?

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  Both switches are in occupancy mode with a lengthy timer.  The switch is made to do this. The bare wires (grounds) are all spliced in the bottom box, and wired to the green screws on the switches. I tried to post pics, but the mobile site and app are both failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the feed from the light,and a switch leg down to first 3way. White has 120 goes to the yellow point. Black and red are travelers. The white on the 3wire goes to the black to the light,load out spliced through.  Upstairs you have now a dead end 3way ,white to yellow point.  Black red travelers.  Down stairs fed and loaded .Upstairs dead end 3way.Re,id the whites with tape or marker.

Comment: Sounds like you have bad splice ,red to yellow ,make black red travelers whites for point and load out